# How to set isMandatory on a field in a ClientScript in Netsuite?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

This is my code:

```js
const cRecord = currentRecord.get();
 const canceledTypeField = cRecord.getField({ fieldId: 'ism_hr_create_edit_canceled_type' });
 canceledTypeField.isMandatory = true;
```

This time, I can't call the currentRecord of the context, because I'm trying to set this property on a Suitelet.

Any idea? thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you've attached the client script using

```
form.clientScriptModulePath = './suitelet_companion_client_CS.js';
```

then you can indeed use the current record module just as in your sample. The field would have been added to the form as:

```
form.addField({
    id:'ism_hr_create_edit_canceled_type',
    type:ui.FieldType.TEXT,
    label:'My Sometimes Needed Field'
})
```

Comment: Hi! Yes but I don't wan't to add a field to my form, I just wanted to make a pair of fields of my existing form in my suitelet "mandatory". The property "isMandatory" doesn't work in my clientScript. Here is my theory: when you call the currentRecord from the module instead of the context, you can not set that property. But, you can set the property "isDisabled", that is confusing. Anyway, my solution was a saveRecord that check if the fields that I needed to be mandatory are empty or not. Thanks for your answer! :)

Comment: If you had a field on a suitelet form then it had been added in the suitelet's code (the server side code) so you could use the N/currentRecord module in the client side code. Maybe mandatory doesn't work but the Field documentation doesn't say it's read only.

Answer (score 0):

Per Suite Answer [85631](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/85631/kw/85631), since the isMandatory property from Field object of the currentRecord module is a read-only field, the proper way to validate a field if it has or has not a value is to use the getValue API on the saveRecord function.  Ex:

```
function saveRecord(scriptContext) {

    var rec = scriptContext.currentRecord;
    var objField = rec.getValue({
        fieldId: 'memo'
    });
    log.debug(objField)
    if(!objField){
        alert('Please enter a value for the Comments Field');
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }

}
```

Or in any Client Script function, you can evaluate the length of the field's value or test for null values.